# g++ linker can't find const member function

Tags: c++, g++, constants, linker-errors

I have a Point class (with integer members x and y) that has a member function `withinBounds` that is declared like so:

`bool withinBounds(const Point&, const Point&) const;`

and defined like this:

```
bool Point::withinBounds(const Point& TL, const Point& BR) const
{
    if(x < TL.getX()) return false;
    if(x > BR.getX()) return false;
    if(y < TL.getY()) return false;
    if(y > BR.getY()) return false;

    // Success
    return true;
}
```

and then in another file, I call `withinBounds` like this:

```
Point pos = currentPlayer->getPosition();
if(pos.withinBounds(topleft, bottomright))
{
    // code block
}
```

This compiles fine, but it fails to link.  g++ gives me this error:

`/home/max/Desktop/Development/YARL/yarl/src/GameData.cpp:61: undefined reference to 'yarl::utility::Point::withinBounds(yarl::utility::Point const&, yarl::utility::Point const&)'`

When I make the function not const, it links fine.  Anyone know the reason why?  The linker error looks like it's looking for a non-const version of the function, but I don't know why it would.

Comment: It would look for a non-const version if the compiler found one and told the linker to link to it.  Under no other conditions would it do so.

Comment: Are you defining both the const and non-const version?

Comment: I'm only defining the const version of it.  There is an overloaded version of the function that takes four ints instead of two Points, but that is const as well, and there's no other `withinBounds` in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like in the calling file, whatever header is included to give the declaration of `withinBounds` has the incorrect declaration, of a non-const version of the method (note that the undefined reference is to a non-const version). Make sure that your project include directories don't include multiple versions of the header. Also make sure that you did in fact change and save the header as you intended.

Comment: I found the problem.  The object file of the calling file was still looking for the old non-const version, and make didn't update it, since none of the code for that object file was changed. Recompiling from scratch fixed it.  Thanks for your help, everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add here for future readers since this is a close result on google, if you are confident that your definitions are correct, try deleting all of your object files (.o) and then recompiling